# Authorized queries with Apollo in Next.js application

Tags: graphql, next.js, apollo, apollo-client, wp-graphql

I'm working on a PWA developed with Next.js that has to read data from a Wordpress site and I'm pretty new to these technologies.

I have these Wordpress plugins installed:

- WPGraphQL
- WPGraphQL CORS
- WPGraphQL JWT Authentication

Specifically, the problem occurs in the initial "login form". This form requires the insertion of only an alphanumeric ID (not username/password).
Upon submitting the form, a GraphQL query is run to the Wordpress endpoint using the ID in the "where" parameter of the query.
Something like:

```
const GET_USER = gql`
    query getTicket($ticketId: String) {
        tickets(where: {ticketId: $ticketId}) {
            nodes {
                Ticket {
                    email
                    firstName
                    lastName
                    ticketId
                }
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

There is no problem with publicly accessible data, everything works.
On the other hand, if I have to request private data (e.g. user email), I need to run an authenticated/authorized query (Authorization: Bearer <token_here>).

I know that in *WPGraphQL JWT Authentication* there are 2 tokens:

- authToken: duration of 5 minutes and then you need to use the refreshToken to generate another one
- refreshToken: 1 year duration

Considering that I do not require the user to enter a username / password in order to perform a mutation Login that allows to generate the tokens, what method can I use? Is there anything like a fixed token with no expiration (that would probably be a security flaw)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend never use a token with no expiry limits, the best practice is to expire token after every 15 minutes and refresh the token.

Checkout this [link](https://jkettmann.com/3-ways-for-authorization-with-graphql-and-apollo) you can see different methods for having authentication  with `graphql` & `apollo server`.